# Electronjs "App threw an error during load, ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, json, electron

Developing an application using electron but I'm getting error when I run `npm start`:

```
$ npm start

> test@1.0.0 start C:\Users\jakeh\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Electron Apps\Test
> electron .

App threw an error during load:

ReferenceError: reauire is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jakeh\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Electron Apps\Test\main.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:808:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:820:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:601:3)
    at loadApplicationPackage (C:\Users\jakeh\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Electron Apps\Test\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:105:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jakeh\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Electron Apps\Test\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:153:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:808:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:820:10)
```

I tried adding:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```

Still no luck.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = reauire('path');

const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let mainWindow;

// Listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready', function(){
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
    // Load html into window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
        protocol:'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
});
```

Screen shot of error: http://prntscr.com/o32uon

Comment: Notice your error says `reauire` is not defined. I think you have a typo on line 3 of your `main.js` file... check that `require` is spelled correctly for all of your imports - you have a typo when importing the `path` package `const path = reauire('path');`

Comment: That fixed it, my bad thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jake:

Just another passerby: is it possible that you meant to say

const path = **require** ('path');

and this is a simple syntax issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, was a typo with an import.